# Can not open exe file with vbs script located in upper folder

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I've made a vbs script with code:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""MainForm.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

This script is running in the folder where MainForm.exe is located. Everything is OK, and MainForm.exe starts running with this script.

But, I need that script to run just one folder up. And here the problem starts (the folder containing MainForm.exe is called Deploy). I've made a script in upper folder:

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""G:\ROOT\KnowledgeBaseProdukcija\Deploy\MainForm.exe""")`

But it's keep telling me this:

[image]

It seems like MainForm.exe gets running, but something is wrong? I've also tried relative path (which is my preferred way), but with same result:

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""..\KnowledgeBaseProdukcija\Deploy\MainForm.exe""")`

I just don't understand what's the difference between two scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your MainForm.exe is looking for files in the working directory. Since it has been called from outside the directory where the `MainForm.exe` binary is lcoated, it won't be able to find what it's looking for.

This is probably something that needs to be fixed in the MainForm application code. It's probably trying to open a file using a relative path and expecting it to be relative from the directory containing teh binary, but it's now actually looking relative to the working directory.

You can work around this by setting the `CurrentDirectory` property of the Shell object:

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.currentdirectory = "G:\ROOT\KnowledgeBaseProdukcija\Deploy\"
shell.Run("""G:\ROOT\KnowledgeBaseProdukcija\Deploy\MainForm.exe""")
```

Inside the `MainForm.exe`s sources use `string thatpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` to find the installation path and use `Path.Combine(thatpath, "./relative/path/to/resource")` to load any files that you expect to be in a path relative to the executable to fix the issue at the source.

Comment: I am running this script from KnowledgeBaseProduckija, but it says that 'The system cannot find the file specified'.

Comment: So set the `shell.currentdirectory` to the  full directory location of your Mainform.exe

Comment: If I change the path in shell.Run to absolute path (just like your example is), it works. But why is relative path not working? path = ..\KnowledgeBaseProdukcija\Deploy\MainForm.exe. You know, I have my program on the USB key - so key's letter is different on different computers. That is why relative path would be the best solution.

Comment: I'm not sure to what the relative path is. It might be relative to the default start-up path of Explorer (c:\windows\system32). Easiest way to check is to actually write the path to the console by invoking something like `%windir%\system32\cmd /c chdir` to see what is actually your base directory.